# specs2 - test with futures, control executing thread

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, specs2

I am using specs2 as my test framework.
I want to test a piece of code which is heavily depended on futures.

For example this is the piece of code:

```
def register(x: Int){
    val f1 = dao1.save(x)
       .map{
         f2 = dao2.save(x)
         f2.onFailure{
            case t => action.revert()      
         }
         f2
       }

    f1.onFailure{
       case t => action.revert()
    }

    f1
}
```

I want to test the scenario in which dao2.save(x) fails.
In this case I expect action.revert() to be executed twice.

The problem is the when I actually test it, while mocking dao2, the assertion occur before the onFailure content get executed.
So on my laptop all tests pass, but on the build server(where stuff is a little slower) it fails.

Any good way to handle this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Await.ready(f1, timeout)` to wait for the future to be finished. Afterwards you can check your assertion.

#### Update

```
val f1 = dao1.save(x)
   .flatMap{
     f2 = dao2.save(x)
     f2.onFailure{
        case t => action.revert()      
     }
     f2
   }

f1.onFailure{
   case t => action.revert()
}

f1

Await.ready(f1, timeout)
```

Comment: This will not work. The future will be finished after 1 second, but the content of the onFailure is a side effect and can happened after the future has returned. @Til Rohrmann

Comment: That is true, because `f2` is of type `Future[T]`, right? What about flattening `f1` by calling `flatMap` instead of `map`? A note, starting a future from within another future will make the execution more or less sequential. Judging from your `map` definition, `f2` does not depend on `dao1.save(x)`. So maybe you can start `dao2.save(x)` concurrently.

Comment: Actually  I want is to be sequential. f2 depends on dao1.save(x). So I can't really run them concurrently..:(

Comment: Fair enough. But what about using a `flatMap` operation instead of a `map` operation and then calling `Await.ready`?

Comment: ok.. here I lost you:).. what do you mean? The first map should be replaced with flatmap? and how Await.ready will help me here?

Comment: Flattening the resulting `Future[Future[T]]` via `flatMap` to `Future[T]` and then calling `Await.ready` on it, will effectively wait for the second (interior) future to be completed. I've updated my answer to reflect my proposal. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Till for your response. I think that this still won't work. f2 future can return but the onFailure handler still can be called after f1 has finished. @Till Rohrmann

Comment: You're right @Tomer. I've got another idea. You can use the `ExecutionContext` of your futures to wait for the completion of all callbacks. If you call `executionContext.shutdown` and subsequently `executionContext.awaitTermination` then `awaitTermination` will only return after all submitted callbacks (up to the point when you called `shutdown`) have been completed. In order to guarantee that both `onComplete` callbacks are submitted you have to wait that `f1` is ready with `Await.ready`. So the only requirement is that you have access to the `ExecutionContext`.